# 大量にある画像のカラープロファイル取得を高速に処理したい

Tags: windows, windows-10, 画像

フォルダ内にある全ての画像のカラープロファイルを一括で取得したいと考えております。
現在はImageMagickを使用してカラープロファイルの一括取得を行っております。しかし速度面でかなり頭を抱えておりまして、ImageMagickに代わる方法で画像のカラープロファイルを取得して、テキスト、CSV、エクセルなどに書き出せたらと考えております。
もし何か良い方法がありましたらご教示お願い致します。

Comment: ディレクトリには何のファイル（ファイル形式）があり、カラープロファイルの何を取得したいのでしょうか？

Comment: あと速度と言うからには何の処理でどのくらいの時間がかかっているか、別の手段で試したことがあるならそれも含めて、具体的で詳細な数値を計測して質問記事に提示した方が良いでしょう。その過程で自分自身で問題のポイントを把握し対処方法を見つけられるかもしれません。そして助言・回答も引き出しやすくなると思われます。

Comment: 失礼しました。ファイル形式はJPEG、TIFFの二種類です。現在の処理時間ですが、60MBのTIFFを取得するのに2秒ほどかかります。

Comment: それは1つのフォルダに千個単位で入っているとかネットワークDISKを使っているとか別の要因なのでは？ あとは検索するとこんな記事が見つかりましたが試してみてはどうでしょう？ [How to extract and examine ICC profiles](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/How_to_extract_and_examine_ICC_profiles) あるいは画像処理を行う有料ソフトならばそうした機能が速い物もあるのでは？

Comment: 1つのフォルダに数万ファイルあり、外付けHDDで取得することを想定しています。複数のPCで処理を行うので汎用性のある方法が好ましいです。いただいたリンクにいくつか紹介されていたので確認してみようと思います。引き続き何か情報があればご教示いただけますと幸いです。お忙しい中素人のご相談に乗っていただき、ありがとうございました。

Comment: お世話になっております。リンクに記載のあったExiftoolを使用した結果、取得に2時間かかっていた処理が、わずか2分で取得できるようになりました。速さに非常に驚いております。ご報告とさせていただきます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 自己解決したのなら、情報共有を兼ねて今までやっていたことの状況・詳細・所要時間などや、ツールを変えた時にそれらをどう変えて対処したかと結果の短縮時間といったことを、質問記事の更新と自己回答の両方でしてみてください。